# name: nil when using Rails Devise and name attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When I create a new User, custom attributes are **nil**.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
    # devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    # devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
end
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

validates :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, presence: true

attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
end
```

seeds.rb

```
User.create(first_name: "User", last_name: "Help", email: "account@email.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
```

Output:

```
#<User id: 5, email: "account@email.com", created_at: "2017-01-31 02:44:32", updated_at: "2017-01-31 02:44:32", first_name: nil, last_name: nil>
```

I am unsure where I went wrong... I followed the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) guide and have read several Stack Overflow questions with similar issues ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084971/devise-user-model-custom-field-always-nil)). I have tried the attr_accessible to no avail.

Update: db/schema.rb

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "",        null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",        null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,         null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "type",                   default: "Account", null: false
t.datetime "created_at",                                 null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                                 null: false
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "confirmation_token"
t.datetime "confirmed_at"
t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true, using: :btree
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `db/schema.rb` ?

Comment: yeah, mrlew is right - maybe you didn't create a migration for the custom fields or you didn't do `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: Added the schema.db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from the model

```
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
```